# CME error says "Unable to read allowed tridion User group"

Tags: web8, cme

I am getting below error on SDL Web 8.1 CME, I don't see anything wrong in user groups other then some disable users

[image]

Comment: Please check the  wcf activation working fine or not?

Comment: This is _not_ a default error message. I says 'tridion' on it. If this was a product message, it would say SDL Web, or - at the very least - it would have a capitalized T for Tridion. Please check your UI extensions and configuration.

Comment: I agree with Nuno -- it is definitely an extension raising that error.

Answer (score 2):

The error is coming from the Translations.com GUI extension. It is from Dashboard.js as it is trying to read configuration data from the TranslateApplication IIS application. It can be caused by the IIS application not being set up correctly, in the most simple case, the IIS application not having been set up.